# Problem running asterisk command through ssh

Tags: ssh, command, asterisk

i need execute remotly an asterisk command via SSH and get the output.
The command to execute is this:

```
asterisk -rx "core show channels"
```

and i run remotely this:

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh HOST asterisk -rx 'core show channels'
```

but i get

```
No such command 'core' (type 'core show help core' for other possible commands)
```

PD: When i run the first command locally I dont get the same, it's runs correctly.
This problem does not happen if i exect a no asterisk command. Example "ls -l"

Any help ?

Comment: When you check locally, are you using the same user?

Comment: Yes, both are root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh HOST "/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx 'core show channels'"